# Enabling "Snapping" in QGIS while drawing polygons?

Tags: qgis, polygon, snapping, digitizing, vector-layer

I tried to draw polygons in QGIS 1.7.0 and somehow I can't find or failed to find the "Snapping" option.

I'm used to ArcGIS 10.0 where you have some snapping options, like placing points of polygons at points/edges/shapes/etc., see image below.

[image: Snipping_in_ArcGIS_10]

Is this also possible with QGIS? And if yes, how to activate it?

I've tried to figure out all the editing options, but couldn't find any snapping or similar.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In `Settings / Options / Digitizing`, you can define the distance radius in pixel or map units to snap to other points.

[image: Settings]

And in `Settings / Snapping options` you can choose which layers can be used for snapping.

In QGIS 3.12, find this under `Project > Snapping options` and a new (possibly docked) window "Snapping and Digitizing Options" will appear (in my case, under the Layers panel).

[image: Snapping]

The only thing that does not work is snapping to the points of a line or polygon you are just creating.

**Software version:** QGIS 2.18.20

Answer (score 7):

Note that in the latest QGIS release `snapping options` is no longer visible by default. To use it right-click `settings` to activate snapping options.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is wondering: you activated the snapping options when this toolbar appears.

[image: snapping options in toolbar]

Comment: Appearing the toolbar is not enough. You have to click the "enable snapping" button if it is not activated.