# QGIS snapping to the points of a line or polygon you are just creating

Tags: qgis

I have the snapping option enabled. I can snap to any point, intersection of created lines.

[image]

But I can't snap to any vertex of the linestring I am just digitizing.

[image]

Is there any option/plugin to activate this feature?

Comment: As AndreJ has noted: "Only thing that does not work is snapping to the points of a line or polygon you are just creating." See this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44846/how-to-enable-snapping-in-quantum-gis-while-drawing-polygons

Comment: @eftas Thanks for your reply. Yes I consulted that thread before posting, but as I saw that was form 4 years ago I decided to open a new one and ask if there has been any change in this 4 years.

Comment: Another question: Why dont you draw a polygon (second example)?

Comment: @eftas it needs to be a Linestring because some of he features of the layer are not closed

Comment: As it doesn't seem to exist yet, it might be a good idea to post a request here if you think it's useful : https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis/issues

Comment: How about trying to create a layer of points which represent the corner points of the polygons you are drawing, then drawing the polygons on a new layer and snapping to the point layer instead?